# Bootstrap card with vertical title

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-cards

i am trying to use a vertical title (image attached) with the boostrap card, but i dont find any example how to do this. Any idea how to do this?

Thanks for your kelp

[Vertical Title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSKXC.png)

Comment: See similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552754/rotate-text-in-bootstrap-in-different-col-sizes

Comment: thanks it can work.