# How to Vertically Bootstrap's List Group Text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to display the text vertically. I've tried a tutorial that has text rotation. But it lefts space in right side. This is a code that I've to try and mixed with a little piece of code from the tutorial:

**1. STYLE:**

```
.list-group-item {
   background: black;
}

.list-group {
   text-align: center;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
   -moz-transform-origin: 100% 0;
   -o-transform-origin: 100% 0;
   transform-origin: 100% 0;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0) rotate(-90deg);
   -moz-transform: translate(-100%, 0) rotate(-90deg);
   -o-transform: translate(-100%, 0) rotate(-90deg);
   transform: translate(-100%, 0) rotate(-90deg);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

**2. LIST**:

```
<ul class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item">A</li>
   <li class="list-group-item">B</li>
   <li class="list-group-item">C</li>
   <li class="list-group-item">D</li>
   <li class="list-group-item">E</li>
</ul>
```

**3. GOAL:**

[image]

**4. RESULT:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
.verticaltext 
 {
    position: relative;
    padding-left:50px;
    margin:1em 0;
    min-height:120px;
 }

.verticaltext-content {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
          filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    left: -40px;
    top: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:26px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

your html structure will look like this:

```
<div class="verticaltext">
  <div class="verticaltext_content">Test 12</div>
</div>
```

you will need to set an absolute position in order to rotate the element in this case `<li></li>`. follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552754/rotate-text-in-bootstrap-in-different-col-sizes) for further clarification